# Unable to access uploaded image from react front-end to spring boot back-end

Tags: java, reactjs, spring-boot

Currently I'm working on a project where I am trying to upload an image from ***react front-end to spring boot back-end***. I am able to successfully upload my image and I stored it in my ***"target/classes/static/public/assets"*** folder. I also store the path in my database which is ***"/public/assets/image_name.jpg"***. After building the ***".jar"*** file when I try to access the image It's giving me this **error** message. But I am able to access those images which I stored it in my ***"/resource/static/"*** folder.

I know it's a configuration problem. But I don't know what I am doing wrong. Cause **ReactJS** can access those "***/resource/static***" folder images after building the "***.jar***" file. So why it cannot access "***/target/static/public/assets***" folder images.

[image]

***The place where I stored my image***

[image]

***Database**:*

[image]

After **"npm run build"** I put all of my **ReactJS** file in my **"/target/classes/static/"** folder

[image]

I really need to know how can I access and render those static images which I stored in my file system after building the jar file

Answer (score 2):

After spending tons of hours I finally solved my problem. And I really understand how static and dynamic resources works in spring boot. It's really easy but unfortunately most of the answers I got from google is very confusing and misleading.

So here is the solution:

There are **two types of static content** we serve in our application:

**first**: the content that we are not going to update when the application is running on web server such as: ***| .css | .js | .html |*** files,
and

**second**: images such as ***| .jpg | .png | .jpeg | .svg |*** which we are mostly going to update or want dynamic behavior. **For example**: Uploading profile picture or changing cover images or hero images, blog post images of your websites.

So in **Spring-Boot** application.
For the **first** **part**: We are going to put our ***| .css | .js | .html |*** files in ***/src/main/resources/static/*** folder. So when we build our project into ***jar*** file it will automatically copy those file and put them into "***/target/classes/static/***" folder. And you will be able to see those static content in your font-end application(**ReactJS**) when you run your server.

Now for the **second parts** you need little bit configuration. You need to create a class which will implements an interface called **WebMvcConfigurer**.

```
@Configuration
public class StaticConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/uploads/**")
                .addResourceLocations("file:" + System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/uploads/");
    }
}
```

Here I am saving my images in:

> "/Users/{your_computer_name}/{proj_name}/uploads/" folder

Thats why I put this in the **addResourceLocations**. And I used absolute path. But you can also use **relative** path like this:

```
registry.addResourceHandler("/uploads/**").addResourceLocations("file:uploads/");
```

It will search your uploaded image relative to your "**.jar**" file location.

After that If you build your **jar** file and run it using terminal or any IDE, you will be able access your uploaded images directly from ***http://localhost:8080/uploads*** and show it in your front-end application without refreshing your webpage or restarting the server.

**Caution**: If you use relative path in **addResourceLocations** make sure your uploaded images folder is relative to your jar file otherwise it will show **404 Not Found** in your browser console.

Say your jar file is in "**Directory**" folder so your uploaded image folder should be inside this "Directory" folder

> /Directory
> ....spring_boot_app.jar
> ..../uploads
> ........avatar.jpg